# Poly Reducer issues in Blender 2.71

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

I am facing difficulties to use Poly Reducer script in current Blender version (v2.71). When I selecting my mesh Edit Mode, I do not see any "Script Window" options inside Mesh menu. I also found in [Blender Wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.4/Py/Scripts/Mesh/Mesh_poly_reduce) that this script is included only in versions 2.42a - 2.46. Unfortunately v2.46 is not supported on my Mac (I tried that).

So I was interested if there is a way to use Poly Reducer script with current Blender version? If yes, how? If no - are there alternative options in Blender to reduce polygons?

Comment: That script is very old and only works in versions up to 2.49b. It's since been replaced by the built in [decimate modifier](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Decimate) as GiantCowFilms mentioned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The **decimate modifier** is the closet alternative. I find *Un-subdivide* to be the best(using even numbers of iterations generally creates better results), the other methods are good to, just try all of them for the best results.

*Note, in Blender 2.4x the decimator didn't support UV's, vertex groups and it triangulated everything, however the decimator now supports these - so there is no need for the script.*

Comment: The Decimate Modifier won't work with Shape Keys. You can however go into Edit mode, and do Decimate Geometry in there, that does work with Shape Keys.